# Flutter Firestore how to update one object in object list?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to remove (or change) one specific object in an object list of one Firestore document.

**Is there a way to tx.update(ref,objectlist.element) directly?**

Right now, I get the document snapshot, I read the object list, modify it, then tx.update the whole objectlist.

```
Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction tx) async {
  DocumentSnapshot postSnapshot = await tx.get(postRef);
  if (postSnapshot.exists) {
    Map<String, dynamic> myMap = Map.from(postSnapshot.data["objList"]);
    myMap.remove(something);

    await tx.update(postRef, <String, dynamic>{"objList": myMap}).then((x) {
      print("leaving document editor");
      _goBackToMain();
    });
  }
});
```

While that works, I'm worried about conflicts if two users try to update the same objectlist at the same time.